# Нужны ли запятые? Уточнение ли это?

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Нужно ли обособлять выделенный фрагмент запятыми? Является ли он уточнением?

*Впервые прототип данного устройства был разработан в Германии **в 1977 году** командой инженеров, работающих на Энгельса.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, обстоятельства отвечают на разные вопросы: где? и когда?